# Using the $in operator through Morphia - doing it wrong?

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

I have the following Play Framework entity (using Morphia for persistence) as part of a generic blogging app:

```
@Entity
public class Comment extends Model {

    ...

    @Reference
    @Indexed
    public SiteUser commenter;

    public static List<Comment> getLastCommentsByUsers(final List<SiteUser> users) {
        final Query<Comment> query ds().createQuery(Comment.class);
        query.field(commenter).hasAnyOf(users);
        return query.asList();
    }

}
```

SiteUser:

```
@Entity(noClassnameStored=true)
public class SiteUser extends AbstractUser {

    public String realName;

}
```

AbstractUser:

```
public class AbstractUser extends Model {

    @Indexed(value= IndexDirection.DESC, unique = true)
    public String emailAddress;

    @Required
    public String password;
}
```

The method `getLastCommentsByUsers()` is supposed to return all comments by the users in the `users` parameter, but I always get an empty `List` back. The reason that `Commment` is a separate collection is to be able to retrieve last X `Comment`s by certain users across their associated `Post`s, which isn't possible if the `Comment` is embedded in the `Post` collection.

Is there something wrong with my query (should I be using something other than `hasAnyOf`), or is it a problem with the relationship mapping - should I be using `ObjectId` instead?

Comment: Please post what your SiteUser class looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `List<Key<SiteUser>>` to query:

```
public static List<Comment> getLastCommentsByUsers(final List<SiteUser> users) {
    final Query<Comment> query ds().createQuery(Comment.class);
    query.field(commenter).hasAnyOf(toKeys(users)); // convert to keys
    return query.asList();
}

public static List<Key<SiteUser>> toKeys(List<SiteUser> users) {
    List<Key<SiteUser>> keys = new ArrayList<Key<SiteUser>>();
    for(SiteUser user: users) {
        keys.add(ds().getMapper().getKey(user));
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Or you can just get the keys by:

```
List<Key<SiteUser>> keys = ds().createQuery(SiteUser.class).query().filter(...).asKeyList();
```

Comment: This returns the following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class org.mongodb.morphia.Key` with Morphia v0.105

Comment: This is a regression and will be fixed in 0.106: https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/529

Answer (score 6):

I use the in() method with a list or set and its working perfectly. Here's a snippet:

```
List<String> keywordList;
List<Product> products = Product.find().field("keywords").in(keywordList).asList();
```

This should work for collection of embedded or references too.