# Morphia - HasAnyOf

Tags: mongodb, morphia

The HasAnyOf feature of Morphia does not seem to be working or Im doing something wrong.

The data is saved correctly on DB.
Im using Morphia 1.0.1 with MongoDB/Drive 3.0.1

Below my class mapping and query:

```
//freight
@Entity(value="freight", noClassnameStored = true)
public class Freight extends BaseEntity {
@Embedded
protected List<Vehicle> vehicles;

//vehicle
@Entity(value="vehicle", noClassnameStored = true)
public class Vehicle extends BaseEntity{...

//Query
Query<Freight> query = getDatastore().createQuery(Freight.class);
    query.disableValidation();

if(vo.getVehicles() != null && !vo.getVehicles().isEmpty()){
        query.field("vehicles").hasAnyOf(vo.getVehicles());     
    }       

    return query.asList();
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work — we are using `.hasAnyOf()` successfully with the same versions.

You should probably change the vehicle entity to

```
//vehicle
@Embedded
public class Vehicle {...
```

Since you are embedding it, it's not a (standalone) entity. I'm not sure what `BaseEntity` does, but if it adds an ObjectId, timestamps,... — that's not necessary for embedded entities, since all the information is already in freight.

Comment: This really works fine. I was making a mistake. Thanks @xeraa

Comment: If it solved the problem, please mark it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the class Vehicle should be referenced instead of embedded, than I changed the mapping and tried to use hasAnyOf and it did not work.

I found a workaround on this post [Using the $in operator through Morphia - doing it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124236/using-the-in-operator-through-morphia-doing-it-wrong) and it worked fine, but its not an elegant solution.

Good to know that hasAnyOf works for embedded objects.

Thank you!